$\mu(B)=\int_B \frac{d\mu}{d\nu} d\nu$
Let $G$ be a locally compact topological group, $\mu, \nu$ be the left and right Haar measures respectively, $k:G\to (0,\infty)$ continuous, $k=\frac{d\mu}{d\nu}$ such that for every $f\in C_c(G)$ $$\int_Gf\,d\mu=\int_Gkf\,d\nu.$$ Prove that for every $B\subseteq G$ Borel $$\mu(B)=\int_Bk\,d\nu.$$
We only need to show that these agree on open sets. Let $U\subseteq G$ be open. It's easy to show that $$\mu(U)\geq\int_Uk\,d\nu$$ since by regularity $$\mu(U)=\sup\left\{\int_Gf\,d\mu:f\in C_c(G),0\leq f\leq 1_U\right\}=\sup\left\{\int_Gkf\,d\nu:f\in C_c(G),0\leq f\leq 1_U\right\}.$$
I would like to know how to show the other direction. Thank you!
